# SVG animation in Safari

Tags: animation, svg, safari

I have an SVG star animation, which is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari desktop or mobile.

Does anybody have an idea why it won't start in Safari?

keyframes also for webkit

```
@keyframes staranimation {
  10% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
    stroke: #a98f22;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    fill: #a98f22;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.3;
    fill: #a98f22;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    fill: #a98f22;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    fill: #a98f22;
    stroke: #a98f22;
  }
}

.star {
    polygon {

    &.fillfirst{
      stroke: #fff;
      -webkit-stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1;
      -webkit-stroke-width: 1;
      fill: #ffff00;
      animation: staranimation 4s linear infinite;
      -webkit-animation: staranimation 4s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: staranimation 4s linear infinite;
      animation-delay: 0.5s;
      animation-delay: 0.5s;
    }
    &.fillsecond {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1;
      fill: #ffff00;
      /* stroke-dasharray: 20;
      stroke-dashoffset: 200; */
      animation: staranimation 4s linear infinite;
      -webkit-animation: staranimation 4s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: staranimation 4s linear infinite;
      animation-delay: 1s;
    }
   }
  }


<div className="stars">
  <svg height="45" width="23" className="star">
    <polygon className='fillfirst' points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="45" width="23" className="star">
    <polygon className='fillsecond' points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" />
   </svg>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's not `className="..."`, it's just `class="..."` (on both SVGs and both polygons).

Comment: in React class is className

Comment: There used to be this bug in safari where if you had the -webkit-animation declared last in order, it expected a matching -webkit-keyframes. So I would get rid of the -webkit-animation completely and see if it fixes this.

Comment: still not working without -webkit-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by importing keyframes from styled-components.

```
const staranimation = keyframes`
 ...
`
```

and then

```
animation: ${staranimation} 4s linear infinite;
```